# Find nearby people in php

Tags: php

I have a lot of user in my app, all of them have a fixed location point I want to create a new section in which users can see other users who are nearby, just like Messenger Wichet and Bitalk , How can I compare the places together and craeat json list for it?

Comment: can you tell us how you are storing user location?

Comment: You have to code it. Seriously, we're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to code for you. Show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and we'll help you - but nobody is going to code for you.

Comment: Well mathematically speaking, you have the **Lat** & **Lon**, you can specify a **radius** and do the maths to get all the users in that zone.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi  in filde of table

Comment: Another option would be to use google maps API to send requests to get the area the **Lat** & **Lon** belongs to - maybe you can also cache this data to speed up the process later - then show the users in the same area as the user.

Comment: @teeyo can you tel me how can call the function ?

Comment: Using the Google maps API http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true You need to specify the **Lat** & **Lon** separated by a comma, you'll get a **JSON** in return with the data needed

Comment: @SureshKamrushi thanks that codes work fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find nearby points from a given distance from any latitude and longitude, we use a spherical trigonometry equation called the Haversine Formula:

```
R = earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
Δlat = lat2− lat1
Δlong = long2− long1
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c
Angles need to be in radians to pass to Trigonometric functions
```

Without being an expert mathematician, this basically translates to the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT *, 
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(55.864237) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-4.251806) ) + sin( radians(55.864237) ) 
 * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM postcodes HAVING distance < 20 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;
```

Above I check for any area within 20 miles, but you can make this as short or long as you want.  The `3959` figure at the start of the query is the number used for miles, if you are using kilometres you should change this number to `6371`.  I have limited it to 1 row, as I only want the closest match, however you may want to change this in other situations!

This is from a little blog post I wrote to remind myself how I did it, you can read it here: https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/geolocate-your-visitors/

Comment: Really nice answer, do you think will this work if some one wants to do this on a real time.  if the user is moving and wants to do the slimier thing ?

Comment: yes, that will work, you just need to pass in the updated lat lng coordinates